# Angular 16 material 16 how set text align for sorted column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with table styling.
I'm using material table component with sorting column.

```
table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table" matSort >
        
  <!-- Created Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear>
      Created
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.created_at | date}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I tried to write in the css file next style. It's work for non sorted column, but doesn't work with sorted.

```
    .mat-mdc-header-cell {
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: open developper tools in your browser, look for the class name. in your css file add the the same class+ higher specificity and style

Answer (score 2):

Use `justify-content: end` to the inner div `.mat-sort-header-container`. <strike>`text-align: right`</strike> won't work as it's `display: flex`

```
.mat-mdc-header-cell {
  color: red;
  .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: end;
  }
}
```